# Animate array element while changing index

Tags: jquery, arrays, slideshow

I have an array with 4 jquery elements.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <img class="image">
 <img class="image">
 <img class="image">
 <img class="image">
</div>
```

In jQuery:

```
var images = $('.image');
```

For my slide effect (for example a slide to the left side) I did something like that (this is not my complete code, the slide effect works!)

```
$('.wrapper').prepend($('.image').last());
$('.wrapper').css('margin-left', '0px');
$('.wrapper').animate({'margin-left', '-100px'}, 1000);
```

My wrapper slides to the left. Now, I want to transform my images while that slide.

```
if(images.index() === 0) {
  // some css for this image (I do my transformation width css transition)
} else if(images.index() === 1) {
  // do some other transformation with css
}
```

I included that `if` inside of my `animate()` (at the moment, inside `complete`).

So my wrapper slides to the left and my array elemets transform like they should but only at the END of the slide animation. I need that transformation while my slide effect.

Like:

```
while(images.index() >= 0 && images.index() <= 1) {// do transformation while this is true}
```

Comment: I changed my array with prepend and append. I need the time while appending or prepending. Thx

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No. I don't know at what time I need to animate my array element. My element 'two' slips from position 2 to 1. While that process I want to transform this element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) You can check some example of this:

- http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified
- http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-static-number-slides
- http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2

Comment: I have a slide animation. I want to change my element while it changes the index position.

Comment: Can you provide me code of your slider or its name?